# How to hide checkbox from Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two link buttons lnkbtn_upcoming and lnkbtn_previous, when any of link button click means then checkbox should hide. Below is my grid view code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Employeedob" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid"
           ShowHeader="False" OnRowDataBound="Employeedob_RowDataBound1">
           <Columns>


    <asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <span class="name">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Ename" Width="150px" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EmpName") %>'></asp:Label></span>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Depart" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval  (Container, "DataItem.CompanyName") %>'>

    </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

 </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Email" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container, "DataItem.EmailId") %>'>

    </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Depart2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container, "DataItem.Department") %>'>

    </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server"  />

</ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
           <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
           <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
           <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <center>
      <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="No Birthday avaliable"
  ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
      </center>
           </EmptyDataTemplate>
       </asp:GridView>
```

My link button design code:

```
  <ul class="pagination pull-right" style="margin: 0px;">
                                    <li>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_Previous"
                                            runat="server"
                                            CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                                            OnClick="lnkbtn_Previous_Click">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                        </asp:LinkButton></li>
                                    <li>

                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_Upcoming"
                                            runat="server"
                                            CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                                            OnClick="lnkbtn_Upcoming_Click">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                        </asp:LinkButton></li>
                                </ul>
```

I am trying to link buttons lnkbtn_upcoming and lnkbtn_previous, when any of link button click means then checkbox should hide. When any link button click then checkbox should hide or not display.

Comment: You mean: when you click lnkbtn_Previous or lnkbtn_Upcoming, you want to hide all checkboxes of your GridView ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I will assume that you want to hide all checkboxes of your GridView whenever you click on lnkbtn_Previous or lnkbtn_Upcoming.

### Client side

I would definetely do that in Javascript with jQuery.

First add a class to your checkboxes :

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" CssClass="hide-on-click" />
```

Then, add a javascript function to hide/show checkboxes :

```
    function toggleCheckboxes(show) {
        // this jquery retrieves an array of 
        // DOM elements with class hide-on-click
        var checkboxes = $('.hide-on-click');
        // look for jQuery API, there must be a function
        // that takes a bool as show/hide parameter
        if (show) checkboxes.show();
        else checkboxes.hide();
    }
```

Finally, in your javascript `lnkbtn_Upcoming_Click()` and `lnkbtn_Previous_Click()` functions, call the function above.

### Server side

This should be avoided since it requires a server round-trip (postback), but maybe you were wondering how to target a specific checkbox since it only has one ID and it is repeated.

If you want to generate client-side code (javascript) involving unique IDs for your checkbox:

- go or generate to the `GridView_RowDataBound` method
- Retrieve the checkbox : `var cb = e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox2");`
- Use its ClientID field to target it against Javascript/jQuery/CSS : `var domId = cb.ClientID;`

Answer (score 0):

I could hide the Checkbox in the LinkButton click event:

```
   protected void lnkbtn_Previous_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       foreach (GridViewRow row in Employeedob.Rows)
       {
       var chk = row.FindControl("CheckBox2") as CheckBox;
       chk.Visible = false;
       }
   }
```